# How to prevent neovim from placing cursor at the last line?

Tags: vim, neovim

Recently I am trying to switch to neovim but there is some annoying cursor movement as you can see below:

[image]

Each echoed text may be followed by cursor at the end. Saving file is quite often command so it is very annoying. The problem may occur when leaving insert mode or even with popup menu when completion takes some time (cursor is placed after the first line of menu). Another example:

[image]

Completion menu based on `completefunc`. It is quite slow and unstable yet but what the hell is this cursor doing?

[image]

Comment: What version of Neovim are you using? What Terminal? What OS? Have you tried running it without your custom settings?

Comment: Ubuntu 16.04, Terminology terminal, NVIM v0.2.3-dev; Build type: RelWithDebInfo. Switching to another terminal (xterm, gnome-terminal) as well as running nvim with `-u NONE` makes no difference.

Comment: Looks like your terminal is just very slow.

Comment: Which one do you use?